# Prefixing function calls with macros

Tags: c, macros

Im running into an issue where I need to be able to modify C function calls via a macro.

The basic structure is like this:

```
#define foo bar
foo_1(x);
foo_2(x);
foo_3(x);
```

What I want is for

```
bar_1(x);
bar_2(x);
bar_3(x);
```

to be called, however the string macro does not seem to replace the prefixed part of the calls.

Can someone point me in the proper direction?

Comment: Well, the preprocessor works on tokens, not text fragments. `foo_1` is a single token.

Comment: That would explain it!  Was thinking it was a find/replace in that kind of example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros only apply to full tokens (thank God - they're bad enough as is). In other words, `#define foo bar` only affects the identified `foo`, not the identifier `foo_1`, because that's not the same token.

If you can't modify the calling code, there is no way to achieve what you want. Use a text editor's search&replace or something like that.

If what you really want is a snippet of function calling code that you can adjust to different name prefixes as needed, you can write it like this:

```
foo(1)(x);
foo(2)(x);
foo(3)(x);
```

and before you include this snippet, you define something like this:

```
#define foo(i) bar_ ## i
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I feared :)  was hoping to save some time with this kinda solution, looks like Ill just skip to the final, and proper, implemenation.

Comment: In my experience you'll never save time doing preprocessor tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

```
➤ cat try.h
#define mymacro(msv) bar_##msv
mymacro(1)(x);
➤ gcc -E try.h
# 1 "try.h"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "try.h"

bar_1(x);
```

Comment: Was about to point out that the old code was invalid, but you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, but the code is too wide-spread to wrap everything with a call like that.  Was hoping this would be a quick fix, looks like I'll just skip to the fina solution.